# How to shift the animation and make it play on a different y-value?

Tags: animation, transforms

I'm new to Blender, so I'd really appreciate a detailed answer to my question.

I downloaded an animation for a moddable game with a low y-value, how can I shift the whole animation (The whole frames) so it can play in the center? Because in-game, half of the animated object appears to be below the surface.
I tried to transfer it using Delta Transform, but whenever I export and re-open it, it returns to its default location (low y-value), so is there a simple solution for this?

I also would like to know, how can I import multiple animation files to the same timeline (use 2 short animations to make a long one)?

Comment: It works best to ask one question per topic. You can create another topic for your question about importing multiple animations.

Answer (score 0):

Select your object, open the *Graph Editor*, unfold the track on the left panel, select the *Y Location* track, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide the others (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide) then move the curve on the editor's Y axis:

[image]